# Left side of nil coalescing operator '??' has non-optional type 'String', so the right side is never used

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, forced-unwrapping

I have a the following code which i am trying to use to initialize a variable and perform some operation on it.

```
let formattedPointsValue: String?
self.formattedPointsValue = model.pointUnitsEarned.stringValueWithWhiteSpaceThousandSeperator()+" "+"model.name".localized(in: .name) ?? .none
```

However i am getting the warning

> Left side of nil coalescing operator '??' has non-optional type 'String', so the right side is never used.

When i remove the `?? .none` my projects runs fine without a problem however when i run my unit tests i get an error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The only way i found to solve this is to use this code.

```
if let unformattedValue = model.pointUnitsEarned {
    self.formattedPointsValue = unformattedValue.stringValueWithWhiteSpaceThousandSeperator()+" "+"model.name".localized(in: .name)
} else {
    self.formattedPointsValue = nil
}
```

I would like to understand why something like this works:

```
let legend: String?
self.legend = model.pointsCategory ?? .none
```

but this fails:

```
let formattedPointsValue: String?
self.formattedPointsValue = model.pointUnitsEarned.stringValueWithWhiteSpaceThousandSeperator()+" "+"model.name".localized(in: .name) ?? .none
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are a little confused with the `??` operator.

You thought this works because `legend` is optional, didn't you?

```
let legend: String?
self.legend = model.pointsCategory ?? .none
```

**That is not the reason!** The actual reason why the above works is because `model.pointsCategory` is optional. It has nothing to do with what's on the left hand side of the `=`. It's all about the operand on the left of `??`. So the above says something like this:

> set `self.legend` to `model.pointsCategory` if `model.pointsCategory` is not nil. If it is nil, set `self.legend` to `.none`.

In this case:

```
self.formattedPointsValue = model.pointUnitsEarned.stringValueWithWhiteSpaceThousandSeperator()+
    " "+"model.name".localized(in: .name) ?? .none
```

Since `"model.name".localized(in: .name)` is not an optional, it does not compile. I suspect that what you intended to do here might be this:

```
if self.formattedPointsValue == nil {
    self.formattedPointsValue = .none
} else {
   self.formattedPointsValue = model.pointUnitsEarned.stringValueWithWhiteSpaceThousandSeperator()+
        " "+"model.name".localized(in: .name)
}
```

Comment: @Erent So do you understand what `??` actually does now?

Comment: @Sweeper  why This code worked :-  
var demoOptinal :String?                    
                                     demoOptinal  = "AB" ?? "B"

Comment: @Amey It does not. It produces a warning.

Comment: Ohk Didnt See Thanx

Answer (score 0):

.name property is not optional thats why error is comming make .name property optional in model

Comment: The .name property is a property from an objective c class. In the project i am working with both OC and swift. Thus i cannnot change the property to optional

Comment: when i try adding brackets i still get this error : Left side of nil coalescing operator '??' has non-optional type 'String', so the right side is never used

Comment: If you have an Objective-C property that is declared as nonnull, but at the same time can return nil, then you are in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

`??` only has a use if the value on the left can be `nil`,

Swift is telling you that it can never be `nil` so the value on the right will never be used. You can remove `: String?` as well.

The value of `model.pointsCategory` is optional, so might be `nil`, which is why it works for that and doesn’t give you any errors or warnings.

The point of the nil coalescing operator is to be able to fall back to a default value if a value doesn’t exist, there’s no point using it if there’s always going to be a value, so that’s why you’re getting a warning.

Comment: So essentially this code will never work ? let formattedPointsValue: String?
self.formattedPointsValue = model.pointUnitsEarned.stringValueWithWhiteSpaceThousandSeperator()+" "+"model.name".localized(in: .name) ?? .none

Answer (score 0):

model.pointUnitsEarned.stringValueWithWhiteSpaceThousandSeperator()+" "+"model.name".localized(in: .name)==> should return the value of optional string

For Example: 
Below code will get the same error which you received

```
let nickName: String = "k"
let fullName: String? = "John Appleseed"
let informalGreeting = "Hi \(nickName ?? fullName)"
```

But below code will work without issues.

```
let nickName: String? = nil
let fullName: String = "John Appleseed"
let informalGreeting = "Hi \(nickName ?? fullName)"
```

So the conclusion is **Coalescing operator '??'** will replace or use default value from Right side to Left. NOT from Left to Right.